# How to make a python executable that for local usage without triggering virus scanner?

Tags: python, windows, macos, security

Creating a prototype python executable for a person who isn't familiar with programming but I can't seem to get it to them without it triggering the virus scanner. I am using pyinstaller to create the executable.

Be able to send a python executable which they can run on their computer without having to install python themselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Aside for the Python executable, it requires other files (like dlls and stuff).  Wouldn't it be easier just to run the .msi file?  You don't need to be a programmer to install anything(though you may need administrator access).  And if the person isn't a programmer, why are you installing python on their system? *rhetorical question really*.

Comment: this way you may create virus for your friend